# Assign value to list property of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please check the controller and model bellow. I am trying to add data to a list property of class `CreateProductPage_IniViewData` but problem is when i try to do it normally in controller it says -

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

So whats wrong i am doing? Any idea?

Model:

```
namespace Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateProductPage_IniViewData
    {
        public string StoreUrl { get; set; }
        public List<ProductGroupFake> productGroup { get; set; }
    }


    public class ProductGroupFake
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
var finalData = new CreateProductPage_IniViewData();

finalData.productGroup.Add(new ProductGroupFake { GroupName = "foo", });


return View();
}
```

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty self-explanatory. Where do you ever assign `finalData.productGroup = new List<ProductGroupFake>();` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in here:

```
var finalData = new CreateProductPage_IniViewData();
```

the `productGroup` inside `new CreateProductPage_IniViewData` is not initialized. simply set it a default value like this:

```
   public class CreateProductPage_IniViewData
    {
        public string StoreUrl { get; set; }
        public List<ProductGroupFake> productGroup { get; set; } = new List<ProductGroupFake>();
    }
```

Or just initialize it before adding to it:

```
var finalData = new CreateProductPage_IniViewData();
finalData.productGroup = new List<ProductGroupFake>();
finalData.productGroup.Add(new ProductGroupFake { GroupName = "foo"});
```